# Rambam's responsum about treating depression with music

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam, music, psych-mentalhealth

I remember reading a tashubho from the Rambam where he clearly states that music can treat depression and therefore it is ok to listen to if you are depressed. However, I can't seem to find it at the moment. Can someone help me out?

Comment: So if you are not depressed you cannot listen to music and look at nice buildings and gardens?

Answer (score 14):

In the introduction to his commentary on *Masekhet Avot* (*Shemonah Peraqim*), [chapter five](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/shmona/5-2.htm), the Rambam says (in Shmuel ibn Tibbon's translation):

> והוא הדין מי שהתרגשה עליו מרה שחורה, ועמד והסירה בשמיעת הניגונים ובמיני הזמר, ובטיול בגינות ובבניינים נאים, ובישיבה עם צורות נאות וכיוצא בדברים שמרחיבים הנפש ומסירים הרהוריו הקודרים ממנה.‏

In an English translation (from [Wikisource](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Eight_chapters_of_Maimonides_on_Ethics/Chapter_V)):

> Similarly, one who suffers from melancholia may rid himself of it by listening to singing and all kinds of instrumental music, by strolling through beautiful gardens and splendid buildings, by gazing upon beautiful pictures, and other things that enliven the mind, and dissipate gloomy moods.

Regarding understanding the Rambam as saying that it's O.K. to listen to music in such a case (and in other cases as well), see "[דעת הרמב"ם והגאונים לענין שמיעת כלי זמר ושירה בזמן הזה](http://www.mishnetorah.com/files/files/shir_himi.pdf)" (PDF).

Comment: you sure he doesn't bring this somewhere in a tashuvoh?

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob he does; it may not be printed in some versions but it's in Shilat's collection of Letters. In Blau ed. its teshuvah 224

Comment: @Matt In [Teshuvah 224](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1731&pgnum=121) in the Blau edition, I don't see it mention using music for treating mental problems, or permitting listening to music on account of it improving the mind or soul (in cases where it otherwise would have been forbidden). If you do, please quote, or cite, where in the _Teshuvah_ it says so.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob I didn't say that there weren't any _Teshuvot_ mentioning this, and am not sure that there aren't.

Comment: @tamir I might have stumbled upon it in a tashubo of in the peirush. Just making sure if is not both lol

Comment: @TamirEvan i have most likely read the part in some scholarly book in my uni. it was a book on the cairo janeezo and medieval spanish/middle eastern philosophy pertaining mainly to rambam zl and his son and their contemporaries. i forget if it was quoted from a tashubo or peirush.

Comment: @TamirEvan i looked in mori qafi7's translation of peirush ha mishno and he has nothing about listening to instrumental music and so on. וכן אם גברה עליו מרה השחורה יסירנה בשמיעת שירים ומיני נגינות, ובטיול בגנות ובניני פאר, וישיבה עם צורות נאות, וכיוצא בזה ממה שמישב את הנפש ומסיר שעמום המרה השחורה ממנה,  thats all i see and i dont see anything about musical instruments specifically could be just "nasheedh" which in arabic means songs without instruments just voice. this is because it is forbidden for muslims to listen to music as well.

Comment: @TamirEvan ודברי שפלות באמת אסור לשמעם ואפילו נאמרו שלא בשירה, ואם שרים אותם עם כלי שיר יהיו שם שלשה אסורים, אסור שמיעת דברי שפלות ונבלות הפה, ואסור שמיעת הנגון כלומר זמרא בפומא, ואסור שמיעת כלי הפריטה. ואם היה זה במקום שיש שתיית יין יהיה אסור רביעי והוא אמרו יתעלה והיה כנור ונבל תוף וחליל ויין משתיהם (ישעיה ה יב). ואם היתה המזמרת אשה יהיה שם אסור חמישי והוא אמרם קול באשה ערוה (ברכות כד א) וכל שכן אם היא מזמרת

Comment: תשובה סימן רכד from mori qafi7 translation

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob (1) In your quote of R.Qafih's translation of _Perush ha-Mishnah_, if "ומיני נגינות" doesn't refer to instrumental music, what does it refer to? (2) In your last two comments, I think I'm missing what you're trying to say. Can you be more explicit about the point you were making?